# Seeing many compilation errors after upgrading my c++ project to VS19

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

I had built a c++ dektop project with VS17.
Now due to certain requirements, I needed it to migrate to VS19.

After making changes to compile my project with VS19, I am seeing many errors like below:

1. C3646 'OVERRIDE': unknown override specifier
2. C2039: 'wstring': is not a member of 'std'

I found this link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c3646?view=msvc-170
but could not find it useful to fix my issue.

I am looking for an easy fix, like if there is a way to use VS17 c++ compiler in VS19.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than going back to the old compiler, you might be better off tackling the errors one-by-one:

**OVERRIDE**: is probably defined as macro somewhere in your project. Find out, what value `OVERRIDE` is being resolved to. Put the cursor into the word `OVERRIDE` to get the value. It could be that the respective include file is not properly included for some reason. Does your old project include a *forced include* for global definitions?

**wstring**: to be recognized as std::wstring, you have to include `<string>`.
Check your `UNICODE` settings. They determine the usage of 8-byte vs. multi-byte characters for strings. Look at `Configuration Properties / Advanced / Character Set` in the solution properties.

Comment: Thank you Axel.
    
I will check and try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use VS 2017 compiler in VS 2019 using "platform toolset" option in properties of project. For this setting install VS 2017 Platform toolset then open project in VS 2019 and go to:
properties/Configuration properties/General/Platform toolset: Visual Studio 2017(V141)

Comment: Although this could be a useful 'quick fix', I would support the notion in [Axel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71466873/10871073) that it would be better to actually address the underlying issues.